# How to pass variable to regular expression in PERL

Tags: regex, perl

Following program is not working. I am not able to replace word with new word using variable (User input)

```
#Perl program that replace word with given word in the string
$str="\nThe cat is on the tree";
print $str;
print "\nEnter the word that want to replace";
$s1=<>;
print $s1;
print "\nEnter the new word for string";
$s2=<>;
print $s2;
$str=~ tr/quotemeta($s1)/quotemeta($s2)/;
print $str
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `s///` operator instead of `tr///`.

The first one means 'substitution': it is used to replace some parts of text (matched by the given pattern) with some other text. For example:

```
my $x = 'cat sat on the wall';
$x =~ s/cat/dog/;
print $x; # dog sat on the wall
```

The second one means 'transliteration': it is used to replace some range of symbols with another range.

```
my $x = 'cat sat on the wall';
$x =~ tr/cat/dog/;
print $x; # dog sog on ghe woll;
```

What happens here is all 'c' were replaced by 'd', 'a' become 'o' and 't' transformed into 'g'. Pretty cool, right. )

[This part](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) of Perl documentation would bring more enlightenment. )

P.S. That was the main logical problem with your script, but there are several others.

First, you need to remove the endline symbols (`chomp`) from the input strings: otherwise the pattern will probably never match.

Second, you should replace `quotemeta` call with `\Q...\E` sequence in the first part of `s///` expression, but drop it altogether from the second (as we replace with *text*, not a pattern).

Finally, I strongly suggest starting using lexical variables instead of global ones - and declaring them as close to their place of usage as possible.

So it becomes close to this:

```
# these two directives would bring joy and happiness in your Perl life!
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $original = "\nThe cat is on the tree";
print $original;

print "\nEnter the word that want to replace: ";
chomp(my $word_to_replace = <>);
print $word_to_replace, "\n";

print "\nEnter the new word for string: ";
chomp(my $replacement = <>);
print $replacement, "\n";

$original =~ s/\Q$word_to_replace\E/$replacement/;
print "The result is:\n$original";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$what = 'server'; # The word to be replaced
$with = 'file';   # Replacement
s/(?<=\${)$what(?=[^}]*})/$with/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Perl program that replace word with given word in the string
$str="\nThe cat is on the tree";
print $str;
print "\nEnter the word that want to replace";
chomp($s1=<>);
print $s1;
print "\nEnter the new word for string";
chomp($s2=<>);
print $s2;
$str=~ s/\Q$s1\E/\Q$s2\E/;
print $str;
```